# Why i can't run c++ code in micropython env esp32

Tags: esp32, micropython

I am following [this](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html) guide to run my C++ code in micropython environment, the normal/simple C++ code works on my ESP32 board but when i try running big loops it gives an error.

The error:

```
$ picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
picocom v3.1

port is        : /dev/ttyUSB0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
hangup is      : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
logfile is     : none
initstring     : none
exit_after is  : not set
exit is        : no

Type [C-a] [C-h] to see available commands
Terminal ready

>>> import cppexample
>>> cppexample.cppfunc()

abort() was called at PC 0x402acc26 on core 0

Backtrace:0x400912c6:0x3ffce1c0 0x40091989:0x3ffce1e0 0x400956ae:0x3ffce200 0x402acc26:0x3ffce270 0x40396985:0x3ffce290 0x40396ac5:0x3ffce2b0 0x400d3d73:0x3ffce2d0 0x400d4f53:0x3ffce390 0x402a7d26:0x3ffce3d0 0x402af51d:0x3ffce680 0x402b55f9:0x3ffce6a0 0x402b5726:0x3ffce6c0 0x402b77e1:0x3ffce6e0 0x402af6f0:0x3ffce780 0x402b55f9:0x3ffce7d0 0x402b5622:0x3ffce7f0 0x402e1847:0x3ffce810 0x402e1b99:0x3ffce8a0 0x402c69b0:0x3ffce8e0


ELF file SHA256: fe8de9466e5c428e

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:4
load:0x3fff0034,len:5572
load:0x40078000,len:12696
load:0x40080400,len:4292
entry 0x40080414
MicroPython v1.16-243-g8c4ba575f-dirty on 2021-09-20; ESP32 module with ESP32
Type "help()" for more information.
>>>
```

I got no idea what's happening,any help is appreciated

Comment: What is a 'big loop'? Add/remove code bit by bit and/or add debug statements to see what goes wrong. In any case: `abort() has been called` isn't from MicroPython but from the C++ libraries, so there's an unhandled exception or out of bounds array access or similar.

Comment: Further to this, 'big' in 'big loop' is *probably* the culprit here.  you really don't have all that much ram to play with.  But we need to see what `cppexample` actually is